# Bad request to the database in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I need to select from the database values on such a request "select * from prem_message where to_id 12 and del_to 0"? 
I writed this query but it is incorrect, please correct it by writing:

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

        // Select a fields from the database
        $criteria->select='id';
        $criteria->select='from_id';
        $criteria->select='to_id';
        $criteria->select='msg';
        $criteria->select='is_read';
        $criteria->select='from_del';
        $criteria->select='to_del';
        $criteria->select='date';

        // Where to_id == current user id and not delete
        $criteria->condition='to_id=:to';
        $criteria->addCondition('to_del=:del','AND');
        $criteria->params=array(':to'=>Yii::app()->user->id);
        $criteria->params=array(':del'=> 0 );

        $model = Message::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

**Error:**

> CDbException
>
> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]:
>   Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT date FROM
>   `prem_message` `t` WHERE (to_id=:to) AND (to_del=:del)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be rewritten as:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    // Select a fields from the database
    $criteria->select='id, from_id, to_id, msg, is_read, from_del, to_del, date';

    // Where to_id == current user id and not delete
    $criteria->condition='to_id=:to';
    $criteria->addCondition('to_del=:del','AND');
    $criteria->params=array(':to'=>Yii::app()->user->id, ':del'=> 0 );

    $model = Message::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

It is because if you assign variable few times - new value overrides all previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You rewrite params. This must fix your error:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    // Select a fields from the database
    $criteria->select='id';
    $criteria->select='from_id';
    $criteria->select='to_id';
    $criteria->select='msg';
    $criteria->select='is_read';
    $criteria->select='from_del';
    $criteria->select='to_del';
    $criteria->select='date';

    // Where to_id == current user id and not delete
    $criteria->condition='to_id=:to';
    $criteria->addCondition('to_del=:del','AND');
    $criteria->params=array(
        ':to'=>Yii::app()->user->id),
        ':del'=> 0
    );
    $model = Message::model()->findAll($criteria);
```